# Where the values of tethering, usb and bluetoth internet are stored?

Tags: root-access, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

I want to disable(or restore to default) the values of Tethering & portable hotspot, deleting the file/s that are storing the config.

Where is located that file?

Comment: `/data/misc/wifi/softap.conf` stores Hotspot SSID and Password. I don't think USB tethering has any setting since you just enable and disable it, and no customization is offered. Bluetooth config file location differs depending upon OEM.